# Accessing array inside an object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am having an Array called Entites, in which i have an object that contains "title", "category" and an array feedbacks.

```
createEntity(title:string,catgory:category){
        if(this.m_role=="Admin"){
          var obj ={"title":title,
                    "category":catgory,
                    feedbacks:['hello']
        };
         this.Entites.push(obj);
        }else{
            console.log("You need to be an Admin to create Entity.");
        }
    }
```

What i want to do is i want to push into this feedback array.
I am trying this

```
//writeFeedback[User]
    writeFeedback(feed:string,titleOfEntity:string){
        if(this.m_role=="User"){
            const to_edit=this.Entites.indexOf({"title":titleOfEntity});
            this.Entites[to_edit].feedbacks.push('Added Feedback');
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't work. On logging 'to_edit' I get -1. What am I doing wrong?
I get this error message on the compilation

```
Property 'feedbacks' does not exist on type 'object'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` for that:

```
  writeFeedback(feed: string, titleOfEntity: string) {
    if (this.m_role == 'User') {
      this.Entites = this.Entites.map((ent) =>
        ent.title === titleOfEntity
          ? { ...ent, feedbacks: [...ent.feedbacks, 'Added Feedback'] }
          : ent
      );
    }
  }
```

**Update:**

```
Property 'feedbacks' does not exist on type 'object'
```

If you have an interface for `entities` then add `feedbacks` to that or create a new interface.

```
interface Entity {
    title: string;
    category: Category;
    feedbacks: string[];
}

// inside the class
Entities: Entity[]
```

Comment: still the same error! feedbacks does not exist on type object.

Comment: You should add an interface for `Entites`.

Comment: @Noob Check the edited answer. There are some typos in your variable names so, change them as you like.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a matching item within an array use map() and indexOf().
Then check the index before updating the indexed array item:

```
const to_edit=this.Entites.map(e => 
   e['title']).indexOf(titleOfEntity);

if (to_edit > -1)        
    this.Entites[to_edit].feedbacks.push('Added Feedback');
```